# Moving an object diagonally inside a square

Tags: math

I am stuck on a particular problem. I am learning on how to create a very basic game, where a ball will travel diagonally from either top left corner of a square or a rectangular down to the bottom right corner in a straight line (As shown in Fig 1 & 2). Now I know that the ball x and y position will both need to be changed frame by frame but I am unsure on how to go about this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD0hD.png)

Math is not my strong point and I am unsure how do I calculate the exact route, especially since both the square and rectangle will have a different angles. Are there any math formulas I can use to calculate the diagonal line and by how much each of the x and y coordinates of the ball will need to be adjusted frame by frame.

From the research that I have done I think that I will most likely need to calculate the angle using the sin or cos functions but I am not sure how everything fits together. Have been using https://www.mathsisfun.com/sine-cosine-tangent.html to try and learn more.

I am planning on starting to code this but would really appreciate answers to these basic questions. I am trying to learn both the programming and the mathematical aspect at the same time and I feel that this approach would be the best fit.

Many Thanks for any suggestions/help, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's rectangular, just calculate the slope: rise (Y) / run (X). That will give you how much to increase the object's location in each direction per frame. Depending on how fast or slow you want the object to move, you'll need to apply some modifier to that (e.g., if you want the object to move twice as fast, you'll need to multiple 2 by the change in a particular direction before you actually change the object's location.

Answer (score 0):

For square :
If you are using Frame or JFrame, you have coordinate with you.

You can move ball from left top to right down as follow ->
Suppose ur top left corner is at (0,0), add 1in both coordinate until you reach right bottom corner.

U can do this using for loop

Answer (score 0):

You don't technically need the angle for this mapping. You know that the formula for a line is "y = m * x + b." I presume that you can calculate m,b. If not, let me know.

Given that - you can simply increment x based on anything you like (timer, event, etc. ). You can place your incremented x into the equation above to get your respective y.

Now, that won't be quite enough as you are dealing with pixels instead of actual numbers. For example, lest assume that in your game x/y are in feet. You will need to know how many pixels represent a foot. Then when you draw to the screen you adjust your coordinates by dividing by pixels per foot.

So...
1. Calculate your m and b for your path. 
2. Use a timer. At each tick, adjust your x value
3. Use your x value to calculate your y value
4. Divide x and y by a scaling number
5. Use the new scaled x and y to plot your object

Now...There are all kinds of tricks you can play with the math, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Let's left bottom corner of rectangle (or square) has coordinates `(x0, y0)`, and right top corner `(x1, y1)`. Then diagonal has equation

```
X(t) = x0 + t * (x1 - x0) 
Y(t) = y0 + t * (y1 - y0)
```

where `t` is parameter in range `0..1`. Point at `t=0` corresponds to `(x0, y0)`, at `t=1` to `(x1, y1)`, and at `t=0.5` - to the center of rectangle. So all you need is vary parameter `t` and calculate position.

When your object will move with constant absolute speed in arbitrary direction, use horizontal and vertical components of velocity `vx` and `vy`. At every moment get coordinates as `x_new = x_old + delta_time * vx`. Note that reflection from vertical edge just changes horizontal component of velocity 'vx = - vx' and so on.